# Ruby Gems / Gemfile : no such file to load -- juggernaut

Tags: ruby, rubygems, irb, gemfile

I have a problem others had before but I can't get anywhere with the answers I found online. When I do:

```
require "juggernaut"
```

in IRB or when I execute a Ruby file with

```
ruby test.rb
```

I get

```
no such file to load -- juggernaut
```

The solution is to add juggernaut to my Gemfile, right?

But where in Redmont is this magical Gemfile? It's not where the Rakefile is. Maybe I have to create a brand new Gemfile from scratch? How would that look like?

And how is "bundler" involved in all this?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you'll need to create `Gemfile`. Bundler will cheerfully do this for you:

```sh
$ bundle init
Writing new Gemfile to /foo/bar/Gemfile

$ cat Gemfile
# A sample Gemfile
source "http://rubygems.org"

# gem "rails"
```

Comment: sorry to bother you but after I did gem install bundler, I still cannot command the shell to do "bundle init" I get "bundle: command not found"

Comment: And what directory would I want the Gemfile in? The same as the Rakefile?

Comment: Did you install bundler? I guess I took for granted that you had, sorry for any confusion. `$ gem install bundler` -- there's further documentation and troubleshooting info [on the official site](http://gembundler.com/). Usually your Gemfile will be in the root directory of your project (which is also where `Rakefile` usually is).

Comment: Great got it. And edited the gemfile: gem 'juggernaut', :git => 'git://github.com/maccman/juggernaut.git' 
Same issue though: no such file to load -- juggernaut (LoadError)